# What mistake am I making in this code (Perl)?

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ("no1"=>1,
         "no2"=>2,
        );

my @array = %hash;

print @array; #Output: no11no22
print "\n";
my $string = print @array; 
print $string; #Output: no11no221
```

Why $string is not same as @array? Why am I getting 1 at the end? What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that `print` doesn't return a string, but rather prints out a string to a filehandle (see `perldoc -f print`).  Instead, you can let `my $string=join('',@array);`

Comment: and returns true (1) if it succeeded, or false if there was an IO error, so the `no11no22` was coming from the `print @array`, and the `1` from the `print $string`

Answer (score 5):

When you assign the value of print you get the value of the variable being printed and the return code, 1 for sucess. See [perldoc print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)

Comment: Oh I see. That's the reason. Thank you marto.